# How can I download a daily report of the installs and uninstalls of my app?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to find a way to download my daily app statistics.  They're available through the developer console and I can download a csv from there, but I'm hoping for something like Apple's Autoingestion tool that I can hook up to a cron to run every day.  The closest I could find was a gsutil command to fetch the monthly sales report, but that's not great.

Is there anything like this?  I know that AppAnnie fetches this information from somewhere, so I feel like it must be out there.  I've had no luck in my search so far, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found this after google for sometime

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2482017?hl=en

Read the section "Automating report downloads using gsutil"
I am not sure are this what you want